# How to find the dispatch id of an event generated by an ActiveX control

Tags: c++, events, event-handling, activex, firebreath

I am writing a wrapper class for an activeX control using FireBreath.

The ActiveX container class has an event sink which listens to the events fired by ActiveX control.

In the code creating the event sink, in the SINK_ENTRY_INFO method one of the parameter is dispatch id of the event.

Where will i find the dispatch id of the event generated by the activeX control?

Answer (score 1):

Get the DISPID the same as you would for any other member on the object.  You can probably use the IDispatchAPI object from firebreath:

https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/IDispatchAPI.cpp#L444

Comment: To clarify, you just call the event as if it were a function, if you're firing the events by wrapping the IDispatch* in an IDispatchAPI object.

Comment: I found it from the inerface events code of the activex controls. Anyways thanks for the links